# Ways to achieve constraint for a T parameter in interface to specific delegate type

Tags: c#, delegates

I know that since C#7.3, we can use T : Delegate constraint.
Could we be more specific - constraint to specific method signature that our interface is relying on (I know code contracts etc arguments, but if we had to)
Something along those lines?

```
public delegate int SummingDelegate(int a, int b);

public interface IRelyOn<T> where T : SummingDelegate
{
    int ConsumingSum(T summingMethod);
}
```

EDIT:
My scenario was to enforce some type of necessary method signatures to be used by a class from an interface that can be mocked and tested.

Comment: Cannot you just use `int ConsumingSum(Func<int, int, int> summingMethod)`? It doesn't make too much sense to constraint to a generic when it cannot be anything else, so I don't think what you're after is possible

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thanks for the response. I agree now that it doesn't make too much sense. After some research, it's not really possible because delegates are sealed classes which (I guess obviously now) cannot be used as base classes for constraint statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics are unnecessary for this scenario, where delegates already represent any method with a matching parameter list and return type.   Simply use the delegate directly:

```
public delegate int SummingDelegate(int a, int b);

public interface IRelyOn
{
    int ConsumingSum(SummingDelegate summingMethod);
}
```

Comment: Exactly that. `T : SomeType` only makes sense if `T` can be either `SomeType`  or a subtype thereof. And a delegate cannot have a subtype (since you can't "inherit" from a concrete delegate).